# Should you redirect or rewrite the ?_escaped_fragment_= URL?

Tags: ajax

Does anyone know what the correct method of redirection handling the AJAX indexing with Google/Bing when dealing with the ?_escaped_fragment_= querystring value? Is it best to redirect the URL (and if so should this be a 302 redirect)? Or is it best to mask the URL with a rewrite to your static content (the URL would stay the same, but your application would route it behind the scenes).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best situation is to avoid any additional HTTP requests all together since search engines are busy enough as it is. Therefore a `rewrite` should be the best solution.